# PERCENTRANK.INC in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to calculate with pandas what Excel gives as a result of PERCENTRANK.INC

The rank in the function name is rather confusing as in fact it simply calculates the number of times a value is inferior to all values of a column, divided by the count of values minus 1, see picture

[image]

The following snippet correctly recalculates the Excel function, although I find it slow, so I wanted to know if there would be a quicker way to do that:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': {0: 13, 1: 12, 2: 8, 3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1}})

print(df)

def func2(t, comp):
    return (df[comp] < t).sum()

df['col1'] = df['col'].apply(func2, comp='col') / (df['col'].count()-1)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is to use apply with axis=1
the below is way faster and mimics the excel function perfectly

```
df2 = df[testcol].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').dropna().to_frame()
df[newcol] = df2.apply(lambda x: (sum(x[testcol] > df2[testcol]) / (df2.count() - 1)).round(3), axis=1)
```